# Spring Boot Application cannot deploy on Wildfly 10.1

Tags: java, spring-boot, jax-rs, wildfly, pom.xml

I am trying to deploy a Spring Boot Application that uses JAXRS to a Wildfly server.

When I do this I get the following error:

```
01:58:46,787 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) Initializing Mojarra 2.2.13.SP1 20160303-1204 for context '/test-spring-boot-jaxrs-demo'
01:58:49,155 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) RESTEASY002225: Deploying javax.ws.rs.core.Application: class test.spring.boot.jaxrs.demo.JerseyConfig
01:58:49,221 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./test-spring-boot-jaxrs-demo: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./test-spring-boot-jaxrs-demo: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:85)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ConstructorInjectorImpl.<init>(ConstructorInjectorImpl.java:47)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.InjectorFactoryImpl.createConstructor(InjectorFactoryImpl.java:53)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.injectedInstance(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:2271)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.JaxrsInterceptorRegistry$AbstractInterceptorFactory.createInterceptor(JaxrsInterceptorRegistry.java:170)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.JaxrsInterceptorRegistry$OnDemandInterceptorFactory.initialize(JaxrsInterceptorRegistry.java:188)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.JaxrsInterceptorRegistry$OnDemandInterceptorFactory.checkInitialize(JaxrsInterceptorRegistry.java:203)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.JaxrsInterceptorRegistry$OnDemandInterceptorFactory.getInterceptor(JaxrsInterceptorRegistry.java:214)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.JaxrsInterceptorRegistry$AbstractInterceptorFactory.postMatch(JaxrsInterceptorRegistry.java:151)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.JaxrsInterceptorRegistry.postMatch(JaxrsInterceptorRegistry.java:421)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.<init>(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:106)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.processMethod(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:281)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.register(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:252)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addResourceFactory(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:222)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addResourceFactory(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:194)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addResourceFactory(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:180)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addResourceFactory(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:157)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addPerRequestResource(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:76)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.registration(ResteasyDeployment.java:409)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.start(ResteasyDeployment.java:250)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.init(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:113)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.init(HttpServletDispatcher.java:36)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.init(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:103)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:250)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.createServlet(ManagedServlet.java:133)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:546)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:517)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.start(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:559)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:101)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
    ... 6 more

01:58:49,221 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "test-spring-boot-jaxrs-demo.war")]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./test-spring-boot-jaxrs-demo" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./test-spring-boot-jaxrs-demo: java.lang.NullPointerException
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException"},
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./test-spring-boot-jaxrs-demo"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => undefined
}
```

The last INFO message before the error talks about deploying class test.spring.boot.jaxrs.demo.JerseyConfig.  I can't seen anything wrong with this code at the moment and deploys ok in Spring Tools Suite using Tomcat 8.5.5.

Does anyone know what could be causing the problem?

**JerseyConfig class:**

```
package psd2.spring.boot.jaxrs.demo;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;

import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        packages("io.swagger.api");
    }
}
```

**POM**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-spring-boot-jaxrs-demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>test-demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Test</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <start-class>test.spring.boot.jaxrs.demo.testDemoApplication</start-class>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
        <swagger-core-version>1.5.12</swagger-core-version>
        <jetty-version>9.2.9.v20150224</jetty-version>
        <jersey2-version>2.22.2</jersey2-version>
        <jackson-version>2.8.7</jackson-version>
        <junit-version>4.12</junit-version>
        <logback-version>1.1.7</logback-version>
        <servlet-api-version>2.5</servlet-api-version>  
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
          <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
              <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
          </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
          <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
          <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs</artifactId>
          <scope>compile</scope>
          <version>${swagger-core-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
          <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
          <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
          <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
          <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
          <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
          <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
          <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
          <version>${jersey2-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
          <artifactId>jackson-datatype-joda</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
          <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Base64 encoding that works in both JVM and Android -->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.brsanthu</groupId>
          <artifactId>migbase64</artifactId>
          <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
       <finalName>test-spring-boot-jaxrs-demo</finalName>
        <plugins>
           <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
              <configuration>
                <archive>
                  <manifest>
                    <mainClass>test.spring.boot.jaxrs.demo</mainClass>
                  </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                  <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
              </configuration>
            </plugin>           
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Central</name>
            <url>http://central.maven.org/maven2/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>   
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

> **UPDATED:** I've reverted JerseyConfig.java code back the above and amended the code to remove Application Path and application appears to deploy but I am seeing a 403 forbidden error.  This application still works when run as a spring boot application using the same URL.

**Logs**

```
16:17:53,779 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.5.2.Final
16:17:54,044 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.6.Final
16:17:54,138 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0049: WildFly Full 10.1.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.2.0.Final) starting
16:17:56,029 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDS0004: Found demo.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called demo.war.dodeploy
16:17:56,055 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0039: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
16:17:56,102 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-4) XNIO version 3.4.0.Final
16:17:56,102 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-4) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.4.0.Final
16:17:56,227 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 33) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
16:17:56,274 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.io] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) WFLYIO001: Worker 'default' has auto-configured to 8 core threads with 64 task threads based on your 4 available processors
16:17:56,274 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) WFLYSEC0002: Activating Security Subsystem
16:17:56,290 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) WFLYCLINF0001: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
16:17:56,290 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSEC0001: Current PicketBox version=4.9.6.Final
16:17:56,305 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) WFLYWS0002: Activating WebServices Extension
16:17:56,493 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) WFLYTX0013: Node identifier property is set to the default value. Please make sure it is unique.
16:17:56,509 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) WFLYNAM0001: Activating Naming Subsystem
16:17:56,540 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYJCA0009: Starting JCA Subsystem (WildFly/IronJacamar 1.3.4.Final)
16:17:56,556 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = h2
16:17:56,556 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) WFLYJSF0007: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main]
16:17:56,634 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 1.4.0.Final starting
16:17:56,743 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYNAM0003: Starting Naming Service
16:17:56,743 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYMAIL0001: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
16:17:56,774 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) WFLYUT0014: Creating file handler for path 'C:\sandbox\apps\wildfly-jboss\wildfly-10.1.0.Final/welcome-content' with options [directory-listing: 'false', follow-symlink: 'false', case-sensitive: 'true', safe-symlink-paths: '[]']
16:17:56,806 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYEJB0481: Strict pool slsb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 64 (per class), which is derived from thread worker pool sizing.
16:17:56,806 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYEJB0482: Strict pool mdb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 16 (per class), which is derived from the number of CPUs on this host.
16:17:57,462 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBoss Remoting version 4.0.21.Final
16:17:57,583 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0012: Started server default-server.
16:17:57,583 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0018: Host default-host starting
16:17:57,708 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on 127.0.0.1:8080
16:17:57,724 WARN  [org.jboss.as.domain.management.security] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYDM0111: Keystore C:\sandbox\apps\wildfly-jboss\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\standalone\configuration\application.keystore not found, it will be auto generated on first use with a self signed certificate for host localhost
16:17:57,755 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\sandbox\apps\wildfly-jboss\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\standalone\deployments
16:17:57,771 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "demo.war" (runtime-name: "demo.war")
16:17:58,333 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-7) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Chakra' 8.2.4.Final
16:17:58,442 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
16:17:58,505 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
16:17:58,510 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
16:17:58,512 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
16:17:58,512 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
16:17:58,527 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
16:17:58,527 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
16:18:00,024 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTPS listener https listening on 127.0.0.1:8443
16:18:00,137 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBWS022052: Starting JBossWS 5.1.5.Final (Apache CXF 3.1.6) 
16:18:01,272 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: /demo
16:18:01,321 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 34) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "demo.war" (runtime-name : "demo.war")
16:18:01,524 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
16:18:01,539 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
16:18:01,539 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: WildFly Full 10.1.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.2.0.Final) started in 8168ms - Started 401 of 651 services (404 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

Comment: I suppose using RESTEasy  would be a good approach. refer this https://developer.jboss.org/thread/271710

Comment: According to the stack trace, RESTEasy is already being used. That may we'll be (part of) the problem given that the code depends on Jersey

Comment: To extend @AndyWilkinson comment, using the `@ApplicationPath` will cause RESTEasy to automatically pick it up and try to configure it. You don't _have_ to use this annotation. 1) With Spring Boot, it already defaults to `/*` (so you can just remove it). 2) If you want to change it, you can configure it with the `application.properties` under the property `spring.jersey.applicationPath`. But you _must_ not use the `Application` in your second attempt. Stick with the `ResourceConfig`. It's what Spring Boot recognizes

Answer (score 0):

I think the only practicable option is to migrate to RESTEasy when moving to WildFly.

Refer [here](http://www.baeldung.com/resteasy-tutorial) .This is a good example.

suppose [this](https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/tree/10.x/helloworld-rs) good place to start.